# Testing Django apps that use South migrations

Tags: django, django-south, django-testing, django-syncdb

I'm trying to create some Functional tests for a Django app that uses South migrations.
Eventually, I will also be creating Twill tests.

When I try to run the existing tests, the test database is not created successfully because of a problem with the South migrations.
( Fails @ 7th of 58 migrations )

It would seem that for the purpose of testing, it's better to build the test database from the Django models, like a syncdb would, than from South.

How do I set up the Django test suite to build the test database from the current model vs. trying to use South?

Comment: But... but your test is failing? What if someone needs to upgrade from your migrations? They can't. Can't you fix the migrations?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The South setting [`SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate) controls this behaviour.

Add this line to your `settings.py` file:

```
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

Comment: Don't you love it when you find an unexpected problem but then the developers already thought of it and included an easy fix?