# Can django testing with databases be fixed for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, django-testing

I have a large django project (AskBot) that I am running the tests for. When I configure `DATABASES` to use sqlite, the tests pass. When I figure to use PostgreSQL, the tests pass, but when I configure to use MySQL, some of the tests fail. By inspecting the test database that is created during testing, I can see that the schema during the tests is missing some fields compared to the real schema. These fields seem to be present when I create the database using `python manage.py syncdb` and `python manage.py migrate`, but not present during the tests.

Is this a common behavior in django, or could someone experienced in django suggest a next step? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't explicitly set [SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate) setting to `False` - test database will be created via south migrations. Try to set it to `False` and see if you will have any difference in schemes between normal `syncdb` and during the test run.

Hope I guessed right.

See also:

- [Django Unit Tests Missing Database Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511209/django-unit-tests-missing-database-columns)
- [Testing Django apps that use South migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572546/testing-django-apps-that-use-south-migrations?rq=1)

Comment: 100% correct! Setting this flag worked marvelously. It begs the follow-up question "why was the migrations failing?", but I guess I'll post that separately...